# Change ListView row color when element is checked true

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, row, background-color

In the drawable folder I've the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@color/checkedItem" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/pressedItem" />
</selector>
```

In my custom adapter XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/checked">
```

In activity:

```
private void ListViewHydromer_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   listViewHydromer.SetItemChecked(e.Position, true);
}
```

But when the item is checked - color doesn't apply to it.

Comment: Try  `android:listSelector="@drawable/checked"`

Answer (score 0):

You are giving reference to checked in `android:background="@drawable/checked">` and you have not mentioned any name called `checked` in your drawable. Replace your checked item with this:

`<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:name="checked"
    android:drawable="@color/checkedItem"/>`

Comment: It's doesn't work( However, if I use `<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/pressedItem" />` it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just changed

```
android:state_checked="true" to android:state_checked="false"
```